(Weak) Commensurability is an equivalence relation on the class of groups
I got stuck trying to do this problem, it is Exercise 5.E.16 in Clara Löh's Geometric Group Theory: An Introduction.  First, let me quote the definitions:

Two groups $G$ and $H$ are commensurable if they contain finite index
subgroups $G'⊂ G$ and $H'⊂H$ with $G'\cong H'$.


More generally, two groups $G$ and $H$ are weakly commensurable if they
contain finite index subgroups $G' ⊂ G$ and $H' ⊂ H$ satisfying the
following condition: There are finite normal subgroups $N$ of $G'$ and $M$
of $H'$, respectively, such that the quotient groups $G'/N$ and $H'/M$ are
isomorphic.

The Exercise asks to show that both commensurability and weak commensurability are equivalence relations on the class of groups.
Clearly, for both notions, the 'hard part' is to prove transitivity of the relation. For commensurability I did this as follows: Let $G_1, G_2, G_3$ be groups such that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are commensurable and $G_2$ and $G_3$ are commensurable. By definition, we find finite index subgroups $$H_1 \subset G_1, \quad H_2 \subset G_2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad H_2' \subset G_2, \quad H_3 \subset G_3,$$ such that $H_1 \cong H_2$ and $H_2' \cong H_3$. Then, consider $H_2'' := H_2 \cap H_2'$; this is a finite index subgroup of $G_2$ being the intersection of two finite index subgroups. Additionally, it's a finite index subgroup of both $H_2$ and $H_2'$. Then, taking $H_1'' \subset H_1$ as the 'copy' of $H_2'' \subset H_2$ under the isomorphism $H_1 \cong H_2$ and similarly $H_3''$, we get that $H_1''$ and $H_3''$ are finite index subgroups of $G_1$ and $G_3$ with $H_1'' \cong H_2'' \cong H_3''$. So, $G_1$ and $G_3$ are commensurable.
For weak commensurability I tried something similar but got stuck: Similarly, we assume there exist finite index subgroups $$H_1 \subset G_1, \quad H_2 \subset G_2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad H_2' \subset G_2, \quad H_3 \subset G_3,$$ but now with finite normal subgroups $$N_1 \subset H_1, \quad N_2 \subset H_2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad N_2' \subset H_2', \quad N_3 \subset H_3,$$ such that $H_1 / N_1 \cong H_2 / N_2$ and $H_2' / N_2' \cong H_3 / N_3$. Since the special case of commensurability corresponds to trivial normal subgroups, I thought we could take a look at the quotient $$\frac{H_2 \cap H_2'}{N_2 \cap N_3}$$ but I do not immediately see how to relate this to the groups $G_1, G_3$.
Thanks in advance!

Hint: Don't intersect the $N_i$, take their product.

[I've corrected this answer to match the question in the text, which asserts that the finite normal subgroups are normal in the finite index subgroups, not necessarily in the entire group.]
This is a little tricky to get right, so I thought I'd post an answer to line it all up. Here's the setup: you have three groups $G_1,G_2,G_3$. You also have $M_i\lhd H_i\le G_i$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$ with both $[G_i:H_i]$ and $|M_i|$ finite, such that $H_1/M_1\cong H_2/M_2$. Similarly there are $N_j\lhd K_j\le G_j$ for $j\in\{2,3\}$ such that $K_3/N_3\cong K_2/N_2$.
The general idea is to find one finite index subgroup $L\le G_2$ and finite normal subgroup $V\lhd L$ that works for both $G_1$ and $G_3$. To that end, define $L=H_2\cap K_2$ and $V=(L\cap M_2)(L\cap N_2)$. Note that $L$ is finite index in $G_2$, $V$ is finite, and $V\lhd L$ since both factors are normal in $L$. Then the second isomorphism theorem shows
\begin{equation}
L/(L\cap M_2) \cong LM_2/M_2\cong L_1/M_1
\end{equation}
for some finite index subgroup $L_1\le H_1$. There is then a finite normal subgroup $V_1/M_1$ such that $L_1/V_1\cong L/V$.
Similar reasoning works to find $L_3\le K_3$ and $V_3\ge N_3$. The following show that all the orders and indices we care about are finite:
\begin{align}
[G_1:L_1] &= [G_1:H_1]\cdot[H_1:L_1] &\qquad |V_1| &= |M_1|\cdot[V_1:M_1]\\
[G_3:L_3] &= [G_3:K_3]\cdot[K_3:L_3] &\qquad |V_3| &= |N_3|\cdot[V_3:N_3]\\
\end{align}
We are then done, because
\begin{equation}
L_1/V_1\cong L/V \cong L_3/V_3
\end{equation}

Oh I just checked the exercise, and I think the OP misquoted it: the normal subgroups are normal in the finite index subgroup, not the whole group. I'll edit this answer to fix that.

Thank you for the well-written answer, it is indeed a little tricky!  Yes I accidentally misquoted the exercise ... You got it right.  I did a simple copy paste from the PDF but the subtle difference is that it for some reason did not copy the $\prime$'s  ^^"
